# Using Mapbox API to load a tile layer, getting 404 error

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm building an app that loads satellite imagery overlays from Astrodigital onto a Leaflet map.

The example [here](https://docs.astrodigital.com/docs/using-processed-imagery-via-leaflet) works fine. My Mapbox key works fine.

I try to use an image I have on Astrodigital, which has this property:

```
"map_id": "astrodigital.6e96e464d72a4647838cd3d014160f1f"
```

This is the formatting:

```
var mbUrl = `https://api.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={token}`;
...
L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'astrodigital.6e96e464d72a4647838cd3d014160f1f', token: accessToken}).addTo(map);
```

But I get a 404 error: 
GET https://api.mapbox.com/v4/astrodigital.6e96e464d72a4647838cd3d014160f1f/...blablabla... 404 (Not Found)

Any ideas on what I should be checking?

Comment: Any reason why you use `api.mapbox.com` whereas the example you mention uses `{s}.tiles.mapbox.com`?

Comment: I tried that one first, no luck either. I looked at the way that the Astrodigital map viewer is calling the tiles, and it was `api.mapbox.com`, so thought I'd try it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your images on Astro Digital are correctly published:

https://publish.astrodigital.com/#astrodigital.6e96e464d72a4647838cd3d014160f1f/31.1977/34.3819/14

You may have an issue with your Mapbox access token.

It looks like not all Mapbox access tokens also provide access to the Astro Digital tiles. Maybe you need an explicit Astro Digital account to get a new API key.

Trying to access your tiles with another Mapbox access token indeed results in 404 errors.

Comment: That was it. Thanks.